# Getting "unary operator expected" in my sh script

Tags: shell, sh, unary-operator

I’m trying to write a startup script for my service using sh but having trouble with the following line

```
#!/bin/sh
…
if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
```

I get the error

```
Starting jboss-as: /etc/init.d/jboss: line 106: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

I can’t tell what is wrong with the eq conditional.  Any advice? - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could reproduce your error is when the `ppid` variable is empty.

```
#! /bin/sh

ppid=''


if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
    echo running;
else
    echo not running;
fi
```

You can check for variable emptyness using

```
if [ -z "$ppid" ]; then 
  echo "ppid is empty;"
fi
```

**EDIT**: Combining both:

```
#! /bin/sh

ppid=


if [[ ! -z "$ppid" && $(ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null) -eq '1' ]]; then
    echo running;
else
    echo not running or pid null;
fi
```

**LAST EDIT**:
Actually your problem comes from not quoting variable expansion:

```
#! /bin/sh

ppid=


if [ $(ps --pid "$ppid" 2> /dev/null | grep -c "$ppid" 2> /dev/null) -eq '1' ]; then
    echo running;
else
    echo not running or pid null;
fi
```

See #5: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/shell-scripting-best-practices.html#BP5

Comment: Ok.  How do you write a combined statement -- e.g. taking account of the fact that the ppid var might be empty?